# Comparing a datetime from a get request with the current date time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to get the difference (in minutes) from a datetime that I get froma  get request in a string format to now.

According to my research, I can use moment.js to do so, but I haven't figured out now.

That format I am getting the date/time to be compared is as:

> 2017-02-10T20:52:13.885Z

I have already tried to do some operations with moment.js such as

```
moment().startof(comparedTime).fromNow())
```

But it returns nothing.

What are the alternatives and the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `moment(dataString, dateFormat).startOf('minutes').fromNow();`?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use vanilla javaScript?

```js
var getDate = '2017-02-10T20:52:13.885Z';  //get time from server
var parseDate = new Date(getDate).getTime();  //change string into Date object into milliseconds
var nowDate = Date.now();  //get current Date in milliseconds

var minutes = Math.round((nowDate-parseDate)/1000/60);  //subtract times, count seconds (/1000), count minutes (/60)

console.log(minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a moment object by passing the date string in. e.g.

```
myDate = moment(myISOString)
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Then you can use the moment object as described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

With Moment.js, this is simply:

```
moment().diff('2017-02-10T20:52:13.885Z', 'minutes') // 65
```

If you want partial minutes included, then pass `true` as a third parameter:

```
moment().diff('2017-02-10T20:52:13.885Z', 'minutes', true) // 65.04565
```